# Preimage of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ with >1 dimension having equal value in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at $C^1$ continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ with $k>1$, typically $k>n$ and the set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^k$, where at least two dimensions have equal value, i.e. $y\in A$ has for some fixed $i$, $y^{(i)}=y^{(j)}$ for at least one $j\neq i$.

Now I am trying to prove that $f^{-1}(A)$ has Lebesgue measure $l(f^{-1}(A))=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, at least if the set $G=\{x\in X:rank(J_f(x))<n\}$ has $l(G)=0$ as well. Alternatively, I would like to find a suitable class of functions $f$ with the stated property.

For $k\leq n$, I believe that [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00970225) provides the exact answer.

For $k>n$, my idea so far is that the relevant points in $\mathbb{R}^k$ all lie on the set $D$ as the union of the diagonals of all $(k,k-1,...,2)$-dimensional (sub-)spaces of $\mathbb{R}^k$. We should then have $l(D)=0$. Now, I would look at $l$ restricted to $D$, $l|D$, as a product measure of $k$ one dimensional Lebesgue measures (is that valid, especially since I restrict to $D$?), $l|D=l^{(1)}|D\times\dots\times l^{(k)}|D$, which should each be zero. Finally, I would use this to justify looking at each dimension of $f(\cdot)$ separately and apply the rationale from [this MO-answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128477/preimage-of-zero-measure-sets#) per dimension.

Please also feel free to tell me if my approach is highly bizarre and what would be best to improve from there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is $f'(X)$ is the definition of $G$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Jacobi-Matrix. Just changed it above.

Comment: So $f$ is supposed to have first-order partial derivatives ?

Comment: Yes, also added that, thanks - anything else that's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be false.

Let $n = 2, k = 3$, and
$$
f(x, y) = (x, x, y)
$$
Then
$$
J_f = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}
$$
has rank $2 = n$ everywhere, so $l(G) = 0$, as required.

On the other hand, $f^{-1}(A)$ is all of $\Bbb R^2$, hence has infinite measure in $\Bbb R^2$.

This example is easily generalized to any higher dimension with $n < k$.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of pointless research!

Comment: You're welcome. To find this, I followed my usual strategy: look for something simple and stupid and see why it *doesn't* provide a counterexample (or get happy when it does). When the first happens, I better understand all the hypotheses of the problem. When the second happens, I learn that more hypotheses were needed, and get to feel clever for a moment. I've seldom encountered an MSE problem where the counterexample was very interesting. Often they're mistaken claims about $\Bbb R^n$ that can be shown wrong for $n = 0$ or $1$, for instance.